# Java vs. Python specific code-fragment performance improvement

Tags: java, python, algorithm, performance

I have a question regarding performance of a specific piece of code in Java and Python.

*Algorithm:*
I am generating **random N-dimensional points** and then for all points under a certain distance threshold of each other I do some processing. The processing itself is not important here as it does not impact total execution time. Generating the points also takes a fraction of a second in both cases, so I am only interested in the part that does the comparing.

*Execution times:*
For a fixed input of 3000 points and 2 dimensions, Java does this in **2 to 4 seconds** while Python takes anywhere **between 15 and 200 seconds**.

I am a little skeptical about the Python execution times. Is there anything I'm missing in this Python code? Are there any algorithmic improvement suggestions (e.g. pre-allocating/reusing memory, a way of lowering Big-Oh complexity, etc.)?

---

**Java**

```
double random_points[][] = new double[number_of_points][dimensions];
for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
  for(d = 0; d < dimensions; d++)
    random_points[i][d] = Math.random();

double p1[], p2[];
for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
{
  p1 = random_points[i];
  for(j = i + 1; j < number_of_points; j++)
  {
    p2 = random_points[j];

    double sum_of_squares = 0;
    for(d = 0; d < DIM_; d++)
      sum_of_squares += (p2[d] - p1[d]) * (p2[d] - p1[d]);

    double distance = Math.sqrt(ss);
    if(distance > SOME_THRESHOLD) continue;

    //...else do something with p1 and p2

  }
}
```

**Python 3.2**

```
random_points = [[random.random() for _d in range(0,dimensions)] for _n in range(0,number_of_points)]

for i, p1 in enumerate(random_points):
  for j, p2 in enumerate(random_points[i+1:]):
    distance = math.sqrt(sum([(p1[d]-p2[d])**2 for d in range(0,dimensions)]))
    if distance > SOME_THRESHOLD: continue

    #...else do something with p1 and p2
```

Comment: I am surprised it takes 2-4 second on Java. I would expect much lower once the JVM warms up. Running this with 3000 points and 2 dimensions it take about 40 micro-second on my machine.

Comment: You might try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378) with the python version.

Comment: You're wasting quite some memory by using `range` over `xrange` and slicing (which creates shallow copies) instead of using `itertools.islice`.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. The question is mostly about Python and whether the execution time could be improved to be in Java's range. 
I am aware of the `range` vs `xrange`, but I forgot to mention I'm running Python 3.2, so that makes it a non-issue and I'll update my post with that in mind. @Mike - definitely a nice general practice tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

I've just tried the following:

```
import numpy
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
D=2
N=3000
p=numpy.random.uniform(size=(N,D))
dist=pdist(p, 'euclidean')
```

The last line computes the distance matrix (this is equivalent to computing `distance` in your code for every pair of points). On my computer it takes about 0.07s.

The main disadvantage of this method is that it requires `O(n^2)` memory for the distance matrix. If that's a problem, the following may be a better alternative:

```
for i in xrange(1, N):
  v = p[:N-i] - p[i:]
  dist = numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(numpy.square(v), axis=1))
  for j in numpy.nonzero(dist > 1.4)[0]:
    print j, i+j
```

For N=3000, this takes ~0.33s on my computer.

Comment: That definitely reduced running time. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If I take 30K points and 5 dimensions, which is 100x more work.

```
int number_of_points = 30000;
int dimensions = 5;
double SOME_THRESHOLD = 0.1;

long start = System.nanoTime();
double random_points[][] = new double[number_of_points][dimensions];
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
    for (int d = 0; d < dimensions; d++)
        random_points[i][d] = Math.random();

double p1[], p2[];
Comparator<double[]> compareX = new Comparator<double[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1[0], o2[0]);
    }
};
Arrays.sort(random_points, compareX);

double[] key = new double[dimensions];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++) {
    p1 = random_points[i];
    key[0] = p1[0] + SOME_THRESHOLD;
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(random_points, key, compareX);
    if (index < 0) index = ~index;
    NEXT: for (int j = i + 1; j < index; j++) {
        p2 = random_points[j];

        double sum_of_squares = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d < dimensions; d++) {
            sum_of_squares += (p2[d] - p1[d]) * (p2[d] - p1[d]);
            if (sum_of_squares > SOME_THRESHOLD * SOME_THRESHOLD) 
                continue NEXT;
        }

        //...else do something with p1 and p2
        count++;
    }
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println("Took " + time / 1000 / 1000 + " ms. count= " + count);
```

Prints

```
Took 1549 ms. count= 20197
```

Answer (score 1):

Does speed really matter?  Here are a couple obvious speed-ups:

1. Don't compute square root.  Just square your threshold and compare against the squared threshold.
2. Sort your points along one dimension (the outer one in your loop).  When two points `i` and `j` are farther than than your threshold on just this dimension, then further incrementing `j` will only produce points farther than this threshold, and you can `continue` the outer loop.

There may be other algorithmic speed ups, even the above is still O(n<sup>d</sup>).